# How to create notification channel for PermissionEverywhere.getpermission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-permissions

I am working on one task where I need to read the data from calendar, as per android documentation, I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

but now when I am using a method

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)
```

it is always returning -1, and permission is denial always, After investigation, I found that I have to request permission at run time, and there are multiple permission required to be granted in my framework,

I found that PermissionEverywhere.getpermission, can solve this issue,

but I am getting error "Developer warning for package  Failed to post notification on channel "null" see log for more details

I tried adding the notification channel using below method

```
   private void createNotificationChannelIfNeeded(int id, String title, String message) {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = title;
        String description = message;
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(title, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

but still getting the same error. please let me know, how to create channel for Permission everywhere class

Comment: Do you ask the user to grant this permission?

Comment: that is the main problem, I am not sure how to request permission in a class that is not an activity class.  To request permission, I have to pass activity class instance as a parameter.

Comment: You cannot request permission from any ui other then activity, which makes sense since, as a user, you don't want apps poking around permissions unless app is opened and visible. You should wait for the user to open app (or pop notification that opens app), then request permission from the activity.

Comment: Right, but I am working with services and using only one activity class.

Comment: If your app is mainly in background I recommend popping notification, which will open new activity (either open existing activity or create new one) for requesting permission